# Why use a concave vs. flat mating target for pogo pins?

Tags: connector, component-selection, spring

I'm doing some research into using spring-loaded pogo pin connectors with a mating target for a project I'm working on. During this [research](https://forum.digikey.com/t/mates-for-spring-loaded-contact-pins/657), I discovered that there is a concave mating target, yet, I have only seen flat ones on products. Why would I pick one over the other?

[image]

If it makes any difference, in my case the pins would slide into place from the side (lateral), rather than coming from the top (axial).

Comment: Well, for one it helps with centering and prevents things from slipping out for whatever reason.

Comment: How will they be used in your project?

Comment: @BruceAbbott rotated in, similar to a DSLR body and lens. But I'm also curious on general use cases.

Answer (score 2):

The concave ones will center the engaging pin and relieve it of lateral pressure.  However, disengaging laterally is better done using a flat surface, or you'll actually be increasing the lateral pressure during engagement and disengagement.  In your application I'd go for the flat ones.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the concave ones would provide better contact and align the slightly wobbly rounded-end spring-loaded pins better.

Not sure why you'd want the flat ones unless they're cheaper and/or more available eg. second-sourced. Maybe easier to wipe clean in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

A regular pointed pin is nice for pads. You might be able to use a concave one on an already pointed object like a pointed 0.1" header.